# How can I make a curl request in ColdFusion?

Tags: api, curl, coldfusion, oauth-2.0, request

I am trying to make a post request to the API of Freshbooks, However, I cannot make it work yet. In the documentation, they show an example of how to make the request using Curl.

Request to api.freshbooks.com/auth/oauth/token:

```
            curl -X POST -H "Api-Version: alpha" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
              "client_secret": "<insert your secret>",
              "code": "<insert your authorization code>",
              "client_id": "<insert your client id>",
              "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:3000/just_an_example"
            }' "https://api.freshbooks.com/auth/oauth/token"
```

I am using ColdFusion and this is the method I have, but I always get a 500 internal server error.

```
function getAccessToken( String code ){
    var httpService = new http();
    var body = {};
    httpService.setMethod("post");
    httpService.setUrl( getApiUrl() );
    httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");
    httpService.addParam(type="header",name="Api-Version",value="alpha");

    body.grant_type = "authorization_code";
    body.client_secret = getClientSecret();
    body.code = arguments.code;
    body.client_id = getClientID();
    body.redirect_uri = "https://mywebsite.com";

    serializedStr = serializeJSON( body );
    var result = httpService.send().getPrefix();

    return result;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dont think you are doing anything with the serialized body, serializedStr. something like this maybe httpService.addParam(type="body",value= serializedStr); Not able to test it at the moment.

Comment: You are right. But that was not the problem. The problem was the way I was building the struct to send it as a parameter to the request. I was doing this body.grant_type instead this body[grant_type]. It worked this way.

Comment: of course, I see it now, .dot notation produces upper case keys https://trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/58091d338067f684e97088380afa0201